# How to burn two DVD5 discs from a DVD9

Tags: dvd-burning

How can I burn two DVD5 discs from a DVD9 which auto plays in DVD players? Do I need to edit any files and how do I create a menu for the second disc?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DVDFab DVD Copy](http://www.dvdfab.com/dvd-copy.htm), it has a feature to split a DVD9 into two DVD5 discs. There are some more pointers in this [post](http://forums.afterdawn.com/t.cfm/f-78/dvd-9_to_two_dvd-5-886171/), one tip is using rewritable discs until you have perfected the process.